# No value accessor for form control with path: 'funder_details -> 0. getting this error while generating dynamic form array

Tags: angular, formarray

```html
<div class="tab-content" id="bt-tab_content_1" >
         <div class="tab-pane show active" id="bt-content_1_1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bt-tab_1_1" formArrayName="funder_details"  *ngFor="let fund of ProgramForm.get('funder_details').controls ; let i =index;" >
            <div class="form-group row"  [formControlName]="i">
                 <div class="col">
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="credit">Select funder</label>
                             <div class=" showcase_content_area">
                               <div class="form-group">
                                  <select id="js-select-example" class="form-control" name="country" formControlName="funder">
                   <option value="Togo">SeaBridge TFX</option>
                   <option value="Guinea-Bissau">Buyer</option>
                    <option value="Laos">Seller</option>
                   <option value="Andorra">Funder</option>
           </select>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="approve">Amount funded</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="$100,000"   formControlName="funded">
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="currency">Percentage</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="100%" value={{per}}% formControlName="percentage">
        </div>
       </div>
        </div>
                                  
       </div>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addFunderDetails()" [disabled]="!isDisabled">+ Add Funder</button>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="mt-2">
                                      <p class="centerDiv">Total: $100,000</p>
                                      <p class="centerDiv" >Pending: ${{sub}}</p>
                                    </div>
```

Component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.ProgramForm = this.fb.group({

      funder_details: this.fb.array([]),


  });
}

  addFunderDetails(): void {
    (this.ProgramForm.get('funder_details') as FormArray).push(this.addFunder());


  }

  addFunder(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      fund: [''],
      Amt_fund: [''],
      per: ['']
    });


  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First In your class you have defined fund,Amt_fund,per as FormControl, but in view you are using different name, When using reactive form both model and view formControl name should be same.

Second Since you using array of formGroup you have to use [formGroupName] directive instead of [formControlName]

**Try this:**

```
<form [formGroup]="ProgramForm">
  <div class="tab-content" id="bt-tab_content_1">
    <div
      class="tab-pane show active"
      id="bt-content_1_1"
      role="tabpanel"
      aria-labelledby="bt-tab_1_1"
      formArrayName="funder_details"
      *ngFor="let fund of arrayC.controls; let i = index"
    >
      <div class="form-group row" [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="credit">Select funder</label>
            <div class=" showcase_content_area">
              <div class="form-group">
                <select id="js-select-example" class="form-control" name="country" formControlName="fund">
                  <option value="Togo">SeaBridge TFX</option>
                  <option value="Guinea-Bissau">Buyer</option>
                  <option value="Laos">Seller</option>
                  <option value="Andorra">Funder</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="approve">Amount funded</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="$100,000" formControlName="Amt_fund" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="currency">Percentage</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="100%" formControlName="per" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addFunderDetails()">+ Add Funder</button>
    <hr />
    <div class="mt-2">
      <p class="centerDiv">Total: $100,000</p>
      <p class="centerDiv">Pending: ${{ sub }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbkepc)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group row"  [formControlName]="i">
```

This div cannot have a formControlName, which is meant for components implementing ControlValueAccessor